# Passing different kinds of layouts to View

Tags: java, android, layout

I have two questions.

1) I would ideally want this signature for my constructor of a class that extends `View`, because it works for any kind of layout.

```
public HexagonView(Context context, float radius, PointF origin, int background, Layout layout) {
```

But, this cannot work because I have to call the constructor with `RelativeLayout` like so:

```
HexagonView hexagon = new HexagonView(this, 75, new PointF(200,300), Color.BLUE, (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main));
```

Can this be changed to accept multiple layouts? For example, if(layout instanceof RelativeLayout) then cast it. (That doesn't seem to work)

2) The reason why I am passing the layout is so I can later add views easily to that same parent layout. I have a feeling that this isn't a safe programming practice. Is this okay, or should I be going about this a different way?

Edit: I think I figured out my first question about why I couldn't pass it. I believe it is because I assumed `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` extended `Layout`, but in fact they extend `ViewGroup`

Answer (score 0):

To capture the signature you have to take a linear or relative layout, you capture its signature in a bitmap by creating the drawing cache enabled true and then get its drawing cache for the layout and store it in a bitmap  and then display that bitmap in the imageview.

You can take help from the following code

First create an inner class signature which extends the View

```
public class signature extends View {
        private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;
        private static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;
        private Paint paint = new Paint();
        private Path path = new Path();
        private float lastTouchX;
        private float lastTouchY;
        private final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();
        public signature(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
        lastTouchX = eventX;
        lastTouchY = eventY;
        return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
        int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
        for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
        float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
        float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
        expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
        path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
        }
        path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
        break;
        default:
        debug("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
        return false;
        }
        invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
        (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
        (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
        (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));
        lastTouchX = eventX;
        lastTouchY = eventY;
        return true;
        }

        private void debug(String string) {
        }

        private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY) {
        if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left) {
        dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
        } else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right) {
        dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
        }
        if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top) {
        dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
        } else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom) {
        dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
        }
        }
        private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) {
        dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
        dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
        }
    }
```

In the main activity create an object of the class signature like

```
signature sign;
mLinearSign.addView(sign, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

and when you want in your program to capture the signature follow the following lines of code

```
 ImageView ImgVwSign;
    Bitmap sign = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 800,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);    
    mLinearSign.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    sign =mContent.getDrawingCache();
    ImgVwSign.setImageBitmap(sign );
```